# Unable to build project using 'dotnet build' after migrating to PackageReference

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a fairly large solution with about 70 projects inside of it.
I have migrated all of the projects to use PackageReference.
My build succeeds when building using visual studio, however when I try to run
"dotnet build" for the projects at the top (one that doesn't reference any other project),
it cannot find ANY of the nuget packages and fails to build. This project is targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2

```
MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Work\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj (in 278 ms).
C:\Work\ProjectA\FolderA\Class1.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found
```

Upon upgrading to PackageReference, the build is supposed to use the global cache for packages located at %USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages, but running "dotnet build" from console fails. The packages are indeed there with proper versions. Here are the things that I have already tried which didn't work

- setting the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable to `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`
- adding `<add key="repositoryPath" value="%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages" />` to Nuget.config file
- clearing all local nuget caches, deleting obj/bin/vs folders

The build succeeds when using MSbuild command and specifying the nuget package path explicity as such:

`msbuild ProjectA.csproj /t:Build /p:NuGetPackagesPath=%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`

I can't find much information about this issue, not sure what else to try. Please advise.

Comment: dotnet build does not work for .NET Framework projects, whether you switch to package references or not.

Comment: It works - we have been using it on our on demand build agents for over a year. "dotnet build" uses MSbuild behind the scenes all the same.

Comment: Forcing `dotnet build` for your .NET Framework based projects is rather risky an approach as the flavour of MSBuild included was for .NET Core projects only. “Have been using it … for over a year” is just an indicator of how long you stay on a risky way, not really something to prove you are right. You are lucky that something was introduced a year ago to improve .NET Framework compatibility in .NET Core SDK, but that does not mean you should rely on that for something else.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. We are planning to update our projects to .NET 6 and higher very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the real issue.
The old versions of .csproj files from 2015 are not compatible with ProjectReference structure. Visual Studio does some magic behind the scenes that makes the builds work.

I used the [migration tool](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) in order to quickly upgrade my csproj files and with a few extra steps I finally am able to build it using CLI.

Here is a discussion on it on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8931)